# Position fixed overlapping issue?

Tags: html, css, css-position

How to prevent a div with `position: fixed` to stay in the outer div and prevent it from overlapping to the footer of the website.

For example, I have a `div`, and I want to scroll the div within the content div between the header and footer sections and not move from the div outside the content.

My code for this:

**HTML**

```html
<div id="fixed_div"></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#fixed_div {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F1F1F1;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 290px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: if you can make a fiddle __ if not put all the code HTML and CSS including footer and container please

Comment: this is the div only to which i am wanted to scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin for jQuery called Waypoints. It allows you to detect when an element has been scrolled to. http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

```
$('.footer').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $('#fixed_div').hide();
});
```

Its API is quite helpful and should be able to suit your needs.

Comment: i am not wanted to use jquery for this.Either there's some solution in css?

Answer (score 0):

You can use overflow:scroll. If your content get overflowed from inner div it get scroll automatically.